# can I use the same class of some ViewResolver in spring-mvc two times with different property "order" to resovler the result from controller?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In one webapp project ,I need to use two `ViewResolver`, one is for `.jsp`. Another one is for `.html`, others say that I can user two `ViewResolver` with different property named `order`,i just wanna know can the two `ViewResolver`s use the same class such as `InternalResourceViewResolver`?

And how do the two resolvers work? the `order`?If the one with highest priority can not find a file using the `String` or 
`ModelAndView` returned from controller ,the next one resolver continues resolving ??

Comment: Yes you can use multiple `ViewResolver`s and no you cannot use 2 `InternalResourceViewResolver` instances due to the way they work.

Comment: I have to user two different types of ViewAndResolers if I wanna do the work as I described?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InternalResourceViewResolver extends UrlBasedViewResolver
You can override 2 methods. Gor them from the Spring sources

```
@Override
protected View loadView(String viewName, Locale locale) throws Exception {
    AbstractUrlBasedView view = buildView(viewName);
    View result = applyLifecycleMethods(viewName, view);
    return (view.checkResource(locale) ? result : null);
}

protected AbstractUrlBasedView buildView(String viewName) throws Exception {
    AbstractUrlBasedView view = (AbstractUrlBasedView) BeanUtils.instantiateClass(getViewClass());
    view.setUrl(getPrefix() + viewName + getSuffix());

    String contentType = getContentType();
    if (contentType != null) {
        view.setContentType(contentType);
    }

    view.setRequestContextAttribute(getRequestContextAttribute());
    view.setAttributesMap(getAttributesMap());

    Boolean exposePathVariables = getExposePathVariables();
    if (exposePathVariables != null) {
        view.setExposePathVariables(exposePathVariables);
    }
    Boolean exposeContextBeansAsAttributes = getExposeContextBeansAsAttributes();
    if (exposeContextBeansAsAttributes != null) {
        view.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(exposeContextBeansAsAttributes);
    }
    String[] exposedContextBeanNames = getExposedContextBeanNames();
    if (exposedContextBeanNames != null) {
        view.setExposedContextBeanNames(exposedContextBeanNames);
    }

    return view;
}
```

As you can see `loadView()` creates view and then checks `view.checkResource(locale)`

if the result is null you replace suffix and try to get the secondary view for the same name.